# How do I cut savoriness of a dish?

Tags: flavor

I had an interesting sandwich the other day. It was tuna spinach wrap but mixed with a mustard blend with a smidgen of capers. Needless to say, it was quite savory. Was there anything I could have told the chef to add (rather than remove) to reduce the savoriness of the dish?

Comment: *Savoury* is an overloaded word so you will probably have to explain better what you mean by it. Do you mean salty? Not sweet enough? Were the mustard and capers coming through too strong?

Comment: Mild, bland cheese cover most sins--but still, you will have to explain in more detail what you didn't like about the sandwich to get a cogent answer, as @ChrisSteinbach suggested above.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbach: Why wouldn't you assume the literal definition, i.e. *umami* flavour? Tuna is generally high in it. It's possible that the OP is using it incorrectly, but it's not an inherently ambiguous culinary term.

Comment: @Aaronut I would not make that assumption because I am not sure how widespread knowledge of *umami* is, and also because none of the ingredients listed are well known as being exceptional sources of umami compared to things like parmesan, fermented soy products, anchovies, Maggie, and the other usual suspects.

Comment: @Aaronut In this case I would assume it means salty/spicy/flavorful as in "sweet vs savory" - that's probably a more commonly known meaning in a non-culinary context. The named ingredients only reinforce that.

Answer (score 2):

Savory usually means spicy & salty.

If you wanted to cut the sharp salty taste of the mustard & capers you could have used a 'sweet mustard' preparation.

I'm not sure if the spinach in the 'tuna spinach wrap' was actually leaf spinach or one of those green 'wraps' like a tortilla?
Spinach has a bit of a metallic taste that some people find sharp. 
Switch to a mild lettuce like Romaine or even ice berg to offset such strong flavors as tina, mustard, & capers.

A bland cheese or mayonnaise can also help balance too much sharpness or 'tang' also.

Comment: I don't know where you get the savory definition.  To me, in general English usage, it means the opposite of sweet.  As in, "Are those muffins sweet or savory?"

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ If you take "spicy" to mean flavorful (not hot), then this is really not that far from your definition. People also often say "sweet or salty".

Comment: I got the definition from the Merriam Webster English dictionary. The opposite of sweet could be sour, salty, (umami), and or spicy as in 'hot'  given what culture you are from.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds as though the distinct caper and tuna flavors were too much for your palette. It is also possible that, smidgeon or not, there was too much of either. If I were you and returning to the same place I would try to cut the flavors

- adding mayonaise or some other fat that would absorb the flavor
- adding mustard to distract from the intensity
- adding lettuce to the wrap to add a fresh, crispness that would mitigate any saltiness
- by reducing the quantity of tuna/capers